# OpenCV displays dark thresholded image

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

OpenCV displays dark thresholded image wheareas the thresholded image looks fine if I colormap the image to gray using matplotlib. I'm having issues in embedding matplotlib's cmap to my tkinter gui interface. Couldn't make the OpenCV to display my thresholded image properly.

How I want the image to look like. (Used cmap=gray to display using matplotlib)

[image: How I want the image to look like. (Used <code>cmap=gray</code> to display using matplotlib)]

How it actually looks with OpenCV. (I want the same results as matplotlib)

[image: How it actually looks with OpenCV. (I want the same results as matplotlib)]

Code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('dataset.tif')
cv.imshow('Input Image',img)

b,g,r= cv.split(img)
cv.imshow('Red Channel',r)
cv.imshow('Green Channel',g)
cv.imshow('Blue Channel',b)
img2= cv.bitwise_not(g)
cv.imshow('Processed Image',img2)

kernel3 = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(13,13))
tophat = cv.morphologyEx(img2, cv.MORPH_TOPHAT, kernel3)
cv.imshow('Top hat',tophat)
thres= 12
maxValue = 14
th, dat = cv.threshold(tophat, thres, maxValue, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

cv.imshow('thresh',dat)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Did you wrote `cv.waitkey()`?

Comment: Furthermore if I recall correctly opencv by dfault uses floating points, so you should shift the values in the 0-255 domain to the 0-1 domain.

Comment: Can you specify how you *loaded* the image (in what format do you load it)?

Comment: img = cv.imread('dataset.tif')
cv.imshow('Input Image',img) - This is how I loaded and yes I wrote cv.waitkey()

Comment: What kind of values do you get when you `print(img)`?

Comment: I'm a beginner. How to check that?

Comment: you write `print(img)` after the `img = cv.imread(..)` command, and check the output on the console.

Comment: The output of the input image which I got is rgb image of retina.

Comment: can you [edit] your question, and provide the full output?

Comment: Sure. Hold on..

Comment: I have provided my full code and attached the resultant images which I get.

Comment: But the *console output* is not in your question (the content the `print(..)` prints on the console).

Comment: Even when I add print(img), I get the same results.

Comment: of course you get the same result. Do you understand what a console is? It is the black window that typically opens with a program, and where you can write content to (or prompt the user for input)..

Comment: I use atom's inbuilt console and it its just blank when I execute with zero errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Basic Thresholding Operations — OpenCV 2.4.13.7 documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html):

> ### Threshold Binary
>
> This thresholding operation can be expressed as:
>
> [image: formula]

Your `maxVal` is `14` -- not very distant from black (`0`).

You should specify `maxVal =` [`255` to get white](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html#what-is-thresholding).

Comment: Thank you. It works now! Also may I know how to know the correct threshold value?

Comment: @AravindhSharma You didn't show the other images so can't say. Perhaps the previous step was dark, too? https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html also suggests that `MORPH_TOPHAT` might introduce dark areas, you're probably interested in `MORPH_OPEN` instead if your goal is to reduce noise.